# Unmarshall query parameters with Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka, unmarshalling, akka-http

I'm trying to read a query parameter in an REST Api I'm building with Akka-http and having trouble unmarshalling it to a domain object. This is my route definition:

```scala
override lazy val getManyRoute: Route = (pathEndOrSingleSlash & get & parameters("userId".as[UserId].?)) { maybeUserId =>
        complete {
            eventService.getEventsBy(maybeUserId)
        }
    }
```

Everything compiles fine, so I am assuming the necessary unmarshalling implicits are in scope. Using curl to test the endpoint, I get the following error:

```sh
➜  ~ curl "localhost:8080/events?userId=6be0f45e-084e-41db-9e5b-e6bc8d208b54"
The query parameter 'userId' was malformed:
expected whitespace or eof got 'be0f45...' (line 1, column 2)%
```

It seems like it's reading just the first character ('6') from the UUID, and for some reason is not including the rest of the string in the parameter. However, if I change the Route definition to read a String and manually "unmarshall" it, it works fine. Something like the following:

```scala
override lazy val getManyRoute: Route = (pathEndOrSingleSlash & get & parameters("userId".?)) { maybeUserId =>
                                                                                    //   ^ no more unmarshalling
        complete {
            eventService.getEventsBy(maybeUserId.map(functionToUnmarshallStringToUserId))
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Is there something I'm missing in the original route definition?

EDIT:

I have narrowed down the problem using the following change to the route, trying to see exactly what `Unmarshaller` was being used:

```scala
    override lazy val getManyRoute: Route = (pathEndOrSingleSlash & get & parameters("userId".?)) { userId =>
        complete {
            val um = implicitly[Unmarshaller[String, UserId]]

            val t = userId map {
                um.apply
            }

            val fuid = t.fold(Future.successful[Option[UserId]](None)) { _.map { a => Some(a) } }
            fuid flatMap { eventService.getEventsBy }
        }
    }
```

The result was the same, but I got a bit more context in the error:
`io.circe.ParsingFailure: expected whitespace or eof got 'be0f45...' (line 1, column 2)`
The problem is that my chain of implicits has eventually led to circe being responsible for unmarshalling the query parameter. Because circe is a json library, it expects strings to be in quotes, and so the following curl request works as expected:

```sh
curl "localhost:8080/events/?userId=%226be0f45e-084e-41db-9e5b-e6bc8d208b54%22"
# note the URL-escaped quotes (%22) around the id
```

So now the problem seems to be that I need multiple unmarshallers for the same class in scope, one to unmarshall directly from plain strings for query parameters, and one to unmarshall from json payloads from request entities. Is there a way to do that using implicits? As suggested in comments, I could use `“userId”.as(uidUnmarshaller)`, but I would prefer to take advantage of implicits if possible.

Comment: I think you should not just expect UserId, you should also pass the unmarshaller to the query definition, something like: “userId”.as(uidUnmarshaller). [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html)

Comment: Howis`UserId` defined?

Comment: To try to be a bit more type-safe, I have an Id class that looks like
`case class EntityId[F](id: String)`
and `UserId` is just an alias:
`type UserId = EntityId[User]`